# How to sort a list by values which can only be gained during the sort process?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int X { get; }

    public int GetSomeValue(List<MyClass> values)
    {
        return valueOfOperation;
    }
}
```

Let's say I have a `List<MyClass>`. I want to sort it by property X. If there are multiple objects with same value of X, I want to sort those by `GetSomeValue(objectsWithSameXValue)` which returns a value of some operation. Said return value is calculated using all objects with equal value of X.

Desired result should look like this:

```
Object    Property X    GetSomeValue({item2, item3, item4})
item1         1          
item2         3              2
item3         3              3
item4         3              9
item5         4
```

Everything is sorted by X. Item2, item3 and item4 are also sorted by GetSomeValue().

Is there anything I can do without huge if...else trees? I tried different approaches, but sooner or later I got lost because it became confusing.

Answer (score 4):

I would try doing the following:

1. Grouping the values by X
2. Sort the list of groups by their key
3. Sort the values within each group by `GetSomeValue(group)`
4. Combine the results back into one big list

```
items.GroupBy(item => item.X)
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
    .SelectMany(group => group.OrderBy(item => item.GetSomeValue(group)))
    .ToList()
```

I'd suggest changing `GetSomeValue(List<MyClass> values)` to `GetSomeValue(IEnumerable<MyClass> values)` if you have the option, so you don't have to call `.ToList()` repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it is an IEnumerable, I just wanted to keep the above code as short as possible and just typed in list w/o thinking about it :D

Any ideas how to extend your code, in case GetSomeValue() returns equal values too and needs to run GetAnotherValue() with the remaining equal objects as arguments?

Comment: Instead of `group.OrderBy(item => item.GetSomeValue(group))`, you could do the same thing again: `group.GroupBy(item => item.GetSomeValue(group)).SelectMany(subgroup => subgroup.OrderBy(item => item.GetAnotherValue(subgroup)))`. That's getting pretty hard to read though, and at that point I'd recommend posting your `GetSomeValue` method here or on CodeReview to see if it could be simplified

Comment: The `GetSomeValue`, `GetAnotherValue` etc methods are pretty simple in itself, but connected to several services so I think it would be a bit messy to post here.

In the end, they all just calculate values which the objects have to be sorted by if the previous value is the same for two or more.

Think about it like a sports league table. If points of some teams are equal, sort by points gathered by those teams against each other and so on.